# Repeating walk cycle

Tags: animation, nla-editor

I seem to be having problems repeating a walk cycle. The book I'm reading says to adjust the scale and set it to repeat 5-6 times. The walk cycle itself is about 40 frames. Though I've scaled it to make it longer and it repeats, the cycle only lasts 40 frames and then resets. It doesn't reach the end of the bar, which is scaled to 120 in the NLA Editor. Is this supposed to happen? Or is it supposed to reach the far end?

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone help?